# Accessing ui-router parent state views from child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some states defined like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('main.product', {
  url: '',
  abstact: true,
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'product/index.html'
    },
    'sidebar': {
      templateUrl: 'product/sidebar.html'
    }
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('main.product.overview', {
  url: '/products/:product_id',
  templateUrl: 'product/overview.html',
  controller: 'ProductOverviewController'
});
```

In my 'main wrapping' controller, i'd like to access the abstract states `views`, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {

  console.log($state.$current.views.sidebar.templateUrl);

});
```

This works if i'm in the parent state `main.product`. However, as expected, this returns undefined for the child state, `main.product.overview`.

How can I access `views` from a child state?

I know I could use a [data object](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects), eg:

```
$stateProvider.state('main.product', {
  url: '',
  abstact: true,
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'product/index.html'
    },
    'sidebar': {
      templateUrl: 'product/sidebar.html'
    }
  },
  data: {
     'sidebar': {
       templateUrl: 'product/sidebar.html'
     }
  }
});
```

Then access like this:

```
console.log($state.current.data.sidebar.templateUrl)
```

But this is not clean, the `templateUrl` would be duplicated.

Is it possible to access `views` from a child state?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to any state by using `get` method

```
$state.get('main.product').views.sidebar.templateUrl
```

Comment: It needs to be dynamic though. Could you do something like: `$state.get(current).views.sidebar.templateUrl`?

Comment: Yes, assuming `current` is your variable that holds state name

Comment: This works for a parent state, but not a child. eg: `$state.get(toState.name).views.sidebar.templateUrl` (`templateUrl` is defined in the parent). Can we access parent `view` from child?

Comment: It can be used from any where (child/parent).

Comment: Yes, but from child state you don't get the parent's `views`, which is exactly what I need. Maybe i'm not understanding you correctly - if I do a `console.log($state.get(toState.name))`, when on the child route, `views` is unavailable, because it's in the parent.

Comment: Right, here's what I meant >> http://plnkr.co/edit/jdGSatZS30cTLEUk3IkT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Rezigned, but it needs to be dynamic. I cannot specifically define each state. How can you use `parent` or something to that effect? `$state.get(parent).views.test` I forked your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KeIWPoNSDS2b7lLvoN64?p=preview

Comment: So, you want `current` state's `parent` (1-level from child) or `root` state (1st level from any child).

Comment: yes, `current` state's parent, to use `views.something`

Comment: Try this `$state.get('^').views.sidebar.templateUrl` will work in child state. `^` is used to refer to parent state

Comment: I get an error with that: `No reference point given for path '^'`. I've tried a few things, like adding `$current` or `$parent` before or inside the `('^')`. Can't see anything obvious from the docs. Any ideas?

Comment: I think maybe you can setup a demo on plnkr.co so that I can fork from yours and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xo52u95w/1/  It's a version of your plunkr - keeping it simple. I have many routes in the actual app :)